# Android login inside url issue

Tags: android

I am trying to get the source of a page. This page requires a form login. I read that in chrome it is still possible to encode the username and password in the url, such as:

https://username:password@stem7.maxnet.co.nz/ispcentre/isp_usersonline.php

Using Chrome on my PC this loads up the page fine and displays a table.

When using HttpsURLConnection to get the source of the page and the table in an android 4.1 application. I get an unauthenticated message: "Your session has expired please login" why would this be?

I've tried using basic authentication but this website requires form authentication. Struggling to find any examples of a working method of form authentication.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Found a long work around involving mySQL